# Smudge Error downloading .pdf from origin using git [error: external filter 'git-lfs smudge %f' failed]

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm running git from command line on Sierra. I get the following error when I run git pull. It asks me for my ssh passphrase twice for some reason; which it never did before

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/nihavd/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Updating 94a3d3c..1ab37b0
Downloading codes/SDE/Kramers.pdf (999.69 KB)
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/nihavd/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Error downloading object: codes/SDE/Kramers.pdf (cbfa6df7cf0a36276bcb9780ae34dea14276fabbaf310775afcffcdad96e58af)

Errors logged to /Users/nihavd/Github/stablebouncer/.git/lfs/objects/logs/20170228T143817.023100613.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs smudge %f' failed 2
error: external filter 'git-lfs smudge %f' failed
fatal: codes/SDE/Kramers.pdf: smudge filter lfs failed
```

The log file says this

```
git-lfs/1.5.6 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.7.4)
git version 2.11.1

$ git-lfs smudge codes/SDE/Kramers.pdf
Error downloading object: codes/SDE/Kramers.pdf (cbfa6df7cf0a36276bcb9780ae34dea14276fabbaf310775afcffcdad96e58af)

Smudge error: Error buffering media file: http: Get https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/alambic/media/8792073/cb/fa/cbfa6df7cf0a36276bcb9780ae34dea14276fabbaf310775afcffcdad96e58af?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIMWPLRQEC4XCWWPA%2F20170228%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170228T193746Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=f1c7a9c0a65504be3193e6cf57655d02719e2ce0a62ee234f956212813080738&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=2167694&token=1: dial tcp 54.231.72.99:443: i/o timeout: 
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
    /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_bblocal_var_buildworker_ports_build_ports_devel_git-lfs/git-lfs/work/git-lfs-1.5.6/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:166
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.NewSmudgeError
    /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_bblocal_var_buildworker_ports_build_ports_devel_git-lfs/git-lfs/work/git-lfs-1.5.6/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:252
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs.PointerSmudge
    /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_bblocal_var_buildworker_ports_build_ports_devel_git-lfs/git-lfs/work/git-lfs-1.5.6/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs/pointer_smudge.go:70
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs.(*Pointer).Smudge
    /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_bblocal_var_buildworker_ports_build_ports_devel_git-lfs/git-lfs/work/git-lfs-1.5.6/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs/pointer.go:65
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands.smudge
    /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_bblocal_var_buildworker_ports_build_ports_devel_git-lfs/git-lfs/work/git-lfs-1.5.6/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/command_smudge.go:89
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands.smudgeCommand
    /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_bblocal_var_buildworker_ports_build_ports_devel_git-lfs/git-lfs/work/git-lfs-1.5.6/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/command_smudge.go:117
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_bblocal_var_buildworker_ports_build_ports_devel_git-lfs/git-lfs/work/git-lfs-1.5.6/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:477
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_bblocal_var_buildworker_ports_build_ports_devel_git-lfs/git-lfs/work/git-lfs-1.5.6/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:551
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands.Run
    /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_bblocal_var_buildworker_ports_build_ports_devel_git-lfs/git-lfs/work/git-lfs-1.5.6/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/run.go:66
main.main
    /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_bblocal_var_buildworker_ports_build_ports_devel_git-lfs/git-lfs/work/git-lfs-1.5.6/git-lfs.go:33
runtime.main
    /opt/local/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:183
runtime.goexit
    /opt/local/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2086

ENV:
LocalWorkingDir=/Users/nihavd/Github/stablebouncer
LocalGitDir=/Users/nihavd/Github/stablebouncer/.git
LocalGitStorageDir=/Users/nihavd/Github/stablebouncer/.git
LocalMediaDir=/Users/nihavd/Github/stablebouncer/.git/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=/Users/nihavd/Github/stablebouncer/.git/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=3
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
BatchTransfer=true
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic
UploadTransfers=basic
GIT_DIR=.git
GIT_REFLOG_ACTION=pull
GIT_PREFIX=
```

Any ideas about what's wrong?

Comment: Many Amazon services, including S3, are experiencing issues at the moment...

Comment: @Brian I don't follow the relevance of this to my query.

Comment: Your error log stated "Smudge error: Error buffering media file: http: Get https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/alambic/media/..." which implies that it was trying to download a file from S3. There was a major S3 outage yesterday, which may have been contributing to your problem. Is the problem still occurring today?

Comment: @Brian. You're right! It works just fine today. Thank you!!